# npm to install angularjs, then require angularjs in my application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm

What I want to do is very basic. I want to install AngularJS v1.5.x using npm and then have it available for me to utilize within my application. All the tutorials I see out there are just downloading the Angular Version from angularjs.org then including it in their `index.html` in a `<script></script>` tag. But I want to use npm to install AngularJS and then make it available for me to use within my `index.html` like a real developer might do!

Here are the commands I've run.

```
$ npm init
$ npm install angular@1.5.7 --save
npm-angular-test@1.0.0 /Users/theDanOtto/Sites/Playground/npm-angular-test
└── angular@1.5.7
```

Here is my basic `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "npm-angular-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "", 
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.7"
  },  
  "devDependencies": {}, 
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },  
  "author": "", 
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I created an `index.js`, but I left it blank. I then added a src tag in my `index.html` to include `index.js`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <title>Html</title>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5  }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My expression simply writes `{{ 5 + 5 }}` instead of `10`. Where am I headed wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either include Angular.js via

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/somefile.js"></script>
```

though i use bower, check were angularJS file is located after installing it via npm

or use [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

npm is only some manager for frontend libraries in your repository, not for including it into the webapp

Comment: In this case "/node_modules/somefile.js" should be "/node_modules/angular/angular.js" (or "/bower_components/angular/angular.js" when using bower) according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular